# Barcode scan using Input as Return key

Tags: pysimplegui

Is it possible to use input in PySimpleGUI to behave like a button event?

I would like to read a scancod (44 characters) in Input, after the automatic reception enters (Return Key), and add this code to a listbox.
I was looking for a documentation, but I can't adapt myself
'' 'window = sg.Window("Keyboard Test", layout, return_keyboard_events = True, use_default_focus = False)' ''
Give me an example, please.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind `"<Return>"` key to your input element, then do something in event loop.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='INPUT')]]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
entry = window['INPUT']
entry.bind("<Return>", "_RETURN")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "INPUT_RETURN":
        print(f"Input: {values['INPUT']}")

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason Yang

First of all, I would like to say thank you so much!!!
Sencondly it's a pleasure answed by someone who is one of the PySimpleGUI contributors. 

Anyway this solve my question, thanks

I'm looking the Documentation (https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#window), trying to understand what mean >> finalize << Window parameter. I'm still a bit confused.

Type: bool, Name: finalize, Meaning: If True then the Finalize method will be called. Use this rather than chaining .Finalize for cleaner code

Comment: Before window finalized, PySimpleGUI just configure everything about layout or settings. Startup tkinter only when sg.Window with option `finalize=True`, `window.finalize()` or `window.read()`. All of them will do the samething to finalize window by tkinter.